# Techkey Usb 3.0 Wifi Adapter - Issues installing Wifi Adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless, adapter

I just picked up a [Techkey Usb 3.0 Wifi Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07D9BBFV6) off Amazon and have a difficult time figuring out how to install it.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The device came with a CD. I tried running the install.sh script but, it was trying to run something from ./driver folder and was giving off an error, as there is nothing actually in the driver folder. The CD had a linux directory with the following folders:

`RTL8811CU（RTL8821CU）_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.3_24795_COEX20170310-1212.20171031`
`RTL8812BU（RTL8822BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_25643.20171212_COEX20171012-5044`

```
➜  ~ lsusb                     
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c521 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

➜  ~ uname -r                                            
4.13.0-45-generic
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update (2/15/2019):

The adapter was running sporadically slow at times.

I posted over at the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412664&p=13838100#post13838100) and it was recommend that I remove this driver and install a different one, suggested by Chili:

Remove the current driver: `sudo dkms remove 8822bu/1.1 --all`

Run each of the following commands one by one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_25643.20171212_COEX20171012-5044.git
cd rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_25643.20171212_COEX20171012-5044
VER=$(cat ./version)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Consider a restart at this point to be sure it's working.

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394372&p=13776566#post13776566

It's working but, I'll need more time to know if it is more stable. I'll update again soon.

---

I was able to get it working thanks to this:

https://forum.peppermintos.com/index.php/topic,6813.msg68924.html#msg68924

> Okay, it looks like you require the 8822bu driver (which contains the
>   IDvendor:IDproduct string for your adapter .. 0bda:b812)
>
> With an active internet connection, open a terminal and run these
>   commands in sequence:-
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install git dkms
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/rtl8822
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> cd ~/rtl8822
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu.git
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> sudo dkms add ./rtl8822bu
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> sudo dkms install 8822bu/1.1
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe 8822bu
> ```
>
> did wireless spring to life ?
>
> If so, does it survive a reboot ?

Wireless sprung to life and it survived reboot. I only wonder if it will survive kernel updates as well?

Comment: It will like survive updates until you get switched to the 4.15 kernel

Comment: Also worked with Xubuntu 18.04 LTS